# Efficient kernel/userspace communication for Linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I’ve got [a Linux kernel module](https://github.com/tarent/sch_jens/tree/master/janz) (a qdisc / network traffic scheduler, but this shouldn’t matter) which needs efficient communication between kernel and user space.

For the communication from kernel to user space, I found relayfs over debugfs very useful, it passes a high-volume amount of debugging information out via a ring buffer, and if userspace misses a page it doesn’t matter much.

For the communication back (specifically, changing the bandwidth limit between 10 and 1000 times a second) I’ve been relying on the normal netlink stuff, i.e. `tc qdisc change …`. This is not only overhead, mildly mitigated with `tc -b -` and piping the commands in via stdin, but also introduces unwanted latency because that command involves more locking than necessary.

I *think* I need an efficient way to write control parameters (currently just one 64-bit number) to kernel space… very often, and with as few locking as possible. The actual updating of the value can probably be done with an atomic write (most likely followed by some kind of barrier so the other CPUs read the new value — I’ll have to read up on that as well)… unsure if I have to change the reading code as well.

relayfs is unidirectional, and buffered, so it wouldn’t be a good fit either.

From what I understand, procfs and sysfs have traditionally been the ways to do this, with sysfs being preferred for new code. From what I see from other users of sysfs though, it invoves an open/write/close cycle every time a quantity is written, and it’s usually converted to a decimal ASCII string instead of using the binary value in host endianness. This doesn’t sound like an ideal fit either.

Additionally, there may be more than one instance of the qdisc in use at any given time, so I need a way to address the correct one. I could use module-global state to keep a list of currently active qdiscs, but that would require locking, so ideally I’d do the fetching of the pointer to the control variables only on open, with locking; writing can then be lockless atomic. On the other hand, one qdisc does not necessarily need more than one writer to its controlling communication channel.

Update: considering adding just another debugfs file (so I can pass the pointers as `data` argument to `debugfs_create_file`) and doing the atomic writing + barrier in the write file operation, then I *think* I need only atomic reading (with a paired barrier) in the user (which runs in softirq context). Is this sound?

Apparently, `atomic64_read_acquire` and `atomic64_set_release` are my friends for this, and the Linux kernel guarantees just casting from/to `u64` will not invoke UB.

Comment: If you just want to do function calls without context switch, maybe look at `VDSO`.  If you want to move a lot of data, then `io_uring`.

Comment: Neither: VDSO is executed in user space, not in kernel space, so it cannot update kernel-side data. And it’s not a lot, just one 64-bit number each time, and `io_uring` is for filedescriptor I/O but I don’t have the file descriptor in the first place. I don’t mid the syscall; the overhead I need to avoid is the qdisc locking, because that throws off the watchdog timer-based rescheduling.